# How to convert a column value to list in Python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, row, multiple-columns

I need to convert the value in the column 'value' to a list format.
The dataframe df:

```
    emp_no  value
0   390     10.0
1   395     20.0
2   397     30.0
3   522     40.0
4   525     40.0
```

Output should be:

```
    emp_no  value
0   390     [5,10.0]
1   395     [5,20.0]
2   397     [5,30.0]
3   522     [5,40.0]
4   525     [5,40.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `map`, as well :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'em_pno':[390,396,397], 'value':[10.0,6.0,7.0]})
df['value'] = df['value'].map(lambda x:[5, x])

# IN
   em_pno  value
0     390   10.0
1     396    6.0
2     397    7.0
# OUT
   em_pno      value
0     390  [5, 10.0]
1     396   [5, 6.0]
2     397   [5, 7.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"emp_no": [1, 2, 3], "value": [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]})

df['value'] = df['value'].astype('object')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     df.at[index, 'value'] = [5, df.at[index, 'value']]

print(df)

#    emp_no      value
# 0       1  [5, 10.0]
# 1       2  [5, 20.0]
# 2       3  [5, 30.0]
```